# How to put text into a text area

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a textfield and say the user types in 52 Jacob Street, I have an arraylist of objects that have a name, address, and phone number. My code goes through the arraylist and finds the matching object then prints it out. Now i'm trying to put this all into a gui, so when I find the matching object how can I print it to the JTextArea? I made my own toString method.

Comment: This is literally what [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) is for. Read through it, find the method you need, use that method.

Comment: I looked in there and tried to use append but append has a String argument. Should I try to write my own append method that can work with my class?

Comment: @Color09 No, just use yourObject.toString() and append it. So just provide a decent `toString()` method in your class (i.e. in the class of yourObject).

Comment: no, you should not. `myarea.setText(myobject.toString())` will work, as will `myarea.append(myobject.toString())`, or `myarea.insert(myobject.toString(),0)`, etc. =) Read through the API, look for all the methods that sound like they might make sense, and then read their descriptions to find the one that's best suited to your need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite the textarea, use `ta.setText(text);` Otherwise, use `ta.append(text);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `setText` method. That should do it.
You may also want to look at the `append` method.

So just use `yourObject.toString()` and append it to the `JTextArea`.
To do this, provide a decent override of the `public String toString()`
method in your class (i.e. in the class of yourObject).

Comment: Here's some example code, I have a text file of different churches and their info.  `code`                           if(input.toUpperCase().equals("ALL")) {
     for (int index = 0; index < churchCount; index++) {
      textArea.setText(churchList[index].toString());
      //System.out.println(churchList[index]);
      textField.setText("");
      //System.out.println();
     }
    } It's not letting me format, ugh this is frustrating